# Using jCrop with CamanJs not working for Responsive Image

Tags: jquery, jcrop, camanjs, responsive-images

I am using CamanJs (a image manipulation tool) to edit my current image and I have integrated jCrop with the CamanJs for cropping purpose following
http://v2-demos.jcrop.org/demos/camanjs.html this source.
It's working fine but problem is that, it is working for images with fixed width. But I need to do this with responsive images.
Here is a live url : http://128.199.175.24/editimg/crate-editor-popup.html
And here is the Script: http://128.199.175.24/editimg/js/corpCaman.js

I think CamanJs don't support images from remote domain so I couldn't create a jsfiddle.

And if there is any other better jquery tool to manipulate image (crop, brightness, hue, blur and so on) please give me a suggestion for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those styles:

```
#interface {
   width: 100%; // why Do you have it 80%?
}
```

and

```
.jcrop-active {
   width: 100% !important /* And because it has inline style: you should try to remove that style or you need to use */;
}
```

PD: Your environment its difficult to reproduce so I didn't test, but let me know results; I think it's a good place to start